# Calling new on instance, like pc.new InnerClass() -- what is going on?

Tags: java, syntax

I'm puzzled by the possibility to call new on an instance, like

```
InnerClass sc = pc.new InnerClass();
```

I understand how to use it, but my question is about fully understanding this. Like:

- Where is it described in the JAVA documentation?
- Is this a recommended solution that should be used, or is there a better way?
- Why doesn't a plain "new" work?

I saw it in a code example, and I have worked out enough to understand that I'm unable to use a plain "new" in a static context.

This is the full context as a runnable example:

```
class ParentClass{
    ParentClass(){
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        ParentClass pc = new ParentClass();
        InnerClass sc = pc.new InnerClass();
    }
    class InnerClass {
        InnerClass() {
            System.out.println("I'm OK");
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: @MarounMaroun It's not illegal.

Comment: @MarounMaroun no, it certainly isn't.

Comment: I misunderstood the question, sorry.

Comment: Inner class is treated as member of outer class. As you know how to access members (variable and methods) using . dot operator so you can access Inner class object like Parent.SubClass sub = new Parent().new Subclass(); if these line is outside of instance method otherwise you can create like SubClass sub = new SubClass();

Comment: @eis minimal edit of code to clarify that it's about inner class and not inheritance/subclass.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Disclaimer:* The terms "parent class" and "sub class" you use are not correct in your example, so my example below will use the correct terms "outer class" and "inner class" (thanks to @eis for the hint).

---

> Where is it described in the JAVA documentation?

See @eis' comment to my answer for a link.

> Is this a recommended solution that should be used, or is there a better way?

It depends – on what you need it for.
If `SubClass` doesn't need any information of an *instance* of `ParentClass`, it could (and should) be either made static or extracted to not be an inner class at all anymore. In that case, you can just call `new` on it without having an instance of `ParentClass`.

> Why doesn't a plain "new" work?

Because `SubClass` may refer to information of the surrounding instance, which requires you to specify that instance. It's not a sub class in the sense that it extends `ParentClass`, but instead its type becomes a *member* of the outer class.

Consider this (and see it in action [here](http://ideone.com/3JQCQi)):

```
public class OuterClass {
    private int field;

    public OuterClass(int field) {
        this.field = field;
    }

    class InnerClass {
        public int getOuterClassField() {
            // we can access the field from the surrounding type's instance!
            return OuterClass.this.field;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        OuterClass parent = new OuterClass(42);

        // prints '42'
        System.out.println(parent.new InnerClass().getOuterClassField());

        // cannot work as it makes no sense
        // System.out.println(new InnerClass().getOuterClassField());
    }
}
```

If you were able to simply do `new InnerClass()`, there's no way of knowing what `getOuterClassField` should return since it is connected to the *instance* of its surrounding type (rather than just the type itself).

Comment: you should be careful about the terminology. Even if OP calls it a subclass, it's not a subclass, it's an inner class.

Comment: For the first point OP asked, for example [this page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) is official documentation on the subject.

Comment: Very quick answer indeed, and great cooperation on the details. I'll need som time grasping it all, but all details are there!

Comment: Correct about inner class. The subclass was a confusing detail that I didn't recognize. I'll consider refactoring the question.